# Windows Phone local database changes listener

Tags: windows-phone, isolatedstorage

I am new to windows phone development and facing an issue. I want my application to act like a listener to any changes being made in local DB. If application is running and any change is made in the DB (e.g by background agent) then the foreground application should be notified right away.

Is there any way I could register some kind of event in my foreground application which is triggered when there is any change in the local DB?

Comment: Through the BG you can only notify that there is some change in the DB but the new data will be available to the user only when the next FG launch happens.